# Computing z-score of multiple groups in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

For a dataframe in Python (see below), I would like to compute z-score of S using the mean and the standard deviation of a group of G to which an element of S belongs to, that is for s of S belonging to a group g of G,

```
s_z = (s - mu(g))/sigma(g).
```

What is the most elegant way to do it?

```
    G         S         
0   B  0.444939  
1   D  0.407554  
2   C  0.460148  
3   B  0.465239  
4   A  0.462691  
5   A  0.016545  
6   D  0.850445  
7   C  0.817744  
8   B  0.777962  
9   C  0.757983  
10  C  0.934829
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `groupby` with lambda function - with `mean` and `std` or pass [`scipy.stats.zscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html), only necessary change default `ddof`:

```
from  scipy.stats import zscore

df['s_z'] = df.groupby('G')['S'].transform(lambda x: (x-x.mean())/x.std())
df['s_z1'] = df.groupby('G')['S'].transform(lambda x: zscore(x, ddof=1))
print (df)
    G         S       s_z      s_z1
0   B  0.444939 -0.630865 -0.630865
1   D  0.407554 -0.707107 -0.707107
2   C  0.460148 -1.397499 -1.397499
3   B  0.465239 -0.522127 -0.522127
4   A  0.462691  0.707107  0.707107
5   A  0.016545 -0.707107 -0.707107
6   D  0.850445  0.707107  0.707107
7   C  0.817744  0.371317  0.371317
8   B  0.777962  1.152993  1.152993
9   C  0.757983  0.075715  0.075715
10  C  0.934829  0.950467  0.950467
```